# vim-cucumber doesn't find definitions

Tags: vim

I'm trying to switch to Vim from Sublime. I do a lot of Cucumber work. A Sublime plugin allows me to jump from the step in feature file to the corresponding step definition. It looks like [vim-cucumber](https://github.com/tpope/vim-cucumber) is designed for that purpose as well. I've installed vim-cucumber using Vundle. However, when I use any of the commands in the vim-cucumber readme (e.g. `[<C-d>` or `<C-W>d`) I always get `E388: Couldn't find definition`. Is there some prior command or configuration I need to run to load the existing definitions for vim-cucumber to work?

Answer (score 1):

The mappings used by that plugin override buit-in mappings that do more or less the same thing (but not for cucumber so that's alright).

The error message you get is associated with those buit-in mappings (`:help e388`) so it looks like the buit-in mappings are not overriden and thus that your plugin is not installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

romani, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. To fix the issue:

- I removed vim-cucumber from my Vundle plugin list in .vimrc
- executed `:PluginClean`
- removed some references to cucumber.vim in my .vim directory that I think I added either via pathogen or manually at some point
- added the plugin back in to .vimrc
- executed `:PluginInstall`

Looks like jumping to definitions is working. Thanks.